# $1/x$ simple integral with different starting conditions

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, initial-value-problems, bounds-of-integration

I simply want to test:

$\displaystyle{\int} \dfrac{1}{T_0\,-\Gamma(h-h_0)}\,\mathrm{dh}$ with $T(h_0) = T_0$

is the same as

$\displaystyle{\int_{h_0}^{h}} \dfrac{1}{T_0\,-\Gamma(h-h_0)}\,\mathrm{dh}$

Actually it should be, but

$\displaystyle{\int} \dfrac{1}{T_0\,-\Gamma(h-h_0)}\,\mathrm{dh} = -\dfrac{\ln(T_0-\Gamma(h-h_0))}{\Gamma} + C \quad \Rightarrow \quad T_0 = -\dfrac{\ln(T_0)}{\Gamma}+C \quad \Rightarrow \quad C = T_0 - \dfrac{\ln(T_0)}{\Gamma}$

whereas

$\displaystyle{\int_{h_0}^{h}} \dfrac{1}{T_0\,-\Gamma(h-h_0)}\,\mathrm{dh} = {\left[-\dfrac{\ln(T_0-\Gamma(h-h_0))}{\Gamma}\right]}^h_{h_0} = -\dfrac{\ln(T_0-\Gamma(h-h_0))}{\Gamma}+\dfrac{\ln(T_0)}{\Gamma}$

or is this natural?

Comment: is Γ the gamma function or a constant?

Comment: it is a constant

Comment: If you equate the two integrals, then the logarithmic term can be cancelled, unless indeterminate, we find that $$T_0-\frac{ln(T_0)}{Γ}= \frac{ln(T_0)}{Γ}\implies T_0=2 \frac{ln(T_0)}{Γ}$$ $T_0$ can be solved for using the polylogarithm function also known as the W-Lambert function.